# Integration limits of a Marginal Probability Density Function with a Triangle-Shaped Boundary

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have given a triangle shaped boundary $M$ of my probability density function in $\mathrm{R}^{2}$, with the limitations beeing:
$$y = 0$$
$$y = x$$
$$y = 2-x$$
and a probability density function
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 cx &\mbox{if } (x,y) \in M \\ 
 0 & \mbox{else}
\end{cases}
$$
where i calculated it to be a probability density function for $c=3$ with the ansatz
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{x}^{2-x}cx\,\mathrm{d}x\stackrel{!}{=}1\;\;\Rightarrow\;\; c=3.$$
So i try to calculate the marginal probability density function $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

For $f_X(x)$ I get
$$f_X(x)=\int\limits_0^1 3x\mathrm{d}y=3x$$

The problem I see now is getting the limits of $f_Y(y)$. I reshaped the inequality $$x<y<2-x$$ to:
$$x<y$$ and  $$x<2-y.$$
These limits seem to make no sense to me. Where is my mistake in order to get the correct limits to calculate my marginal probability density function?

Comment: Sorry, I was using line $x=0$ instead of $y=0$ as the boundary! So ignore what I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $c$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 &=& \int_{y=0}^{1} \int_{x=y}^{2-y} cx\;dx\;dy \\
&=& c\int_{y=0}^{1} \left[x^2/2 \right]_{x=y}^{2-y} \;dy \\
&=& c\int_{y=0}^{1} \left(2-2y \right) \;dy \\
&=& c \left[2y-y^2 \right]_{y=0}^{1} \\
&=& c \left(2-1 \right) \\
\therefore\quad c &=& 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

For $f_Y(y)$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Y(y) &=& \int_{x=y}^{2-y} x\;dx \\
&=& \left[x^2/2\right]_{x=y}^{2-y} \\
&=& \dfrac{(2-y)^2-y^2}{2} \\
&=& 2-2y \qquad\text{for $0\lt y\lt 1$}.
\end{eqnarray*}

For $f_X(x)$ we need to split into two cases, each with a different upper limit of integration.

If $0\lt x\lt 1$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_X(x) &=& \int_{y=0}^{x} x\;dy \\
&=& \left[xy\right]_{y=0}^{x} \\
&=& x^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

If $1\lt x\lt 2$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_X(x) &=& \int_{y=0}^{2-x} x\;dy \\
&=& \left[xy\right]_{y=0}^{2-x} \\
&=& 2x-x^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

So that gives us,

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2,  & \text{if $0\lt x\lt 1$} \\
2x-x^2, & \text{if $1\lt x\lt 2$.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @user69453 I revised my answer. Hopefully it's better now. :-) Apologies again.

Comment: Oh well this looks pretty good; I will recalculate it, and then accept this as an answer :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we need the true bounds of integration, which are a little different from what you mentioned. Here is a Wolfram Alpha plot of the bounds:
[image: Wolfram Alpha plot of:{y=x,y=2-x,y=0}]

If you integrate this with $x$ as the free variable, you end up with a two-stage integration, since the $y(x)$ function changes at $x=1$. As a result, I would recommend integrating with $y$ as the free variable.
$$y=2-x \rightarrow x=2-y$$
$$y=x \rightarrow x=y$$
$$\int_0^1 \int_{x=y}^{x=2-y} cx dxdy$$
Factor and integrate inside.
$$c*\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2} \rbrack_{y}^{2-y} dy$$
Expand.
$$c*\int_0^1 \frac{-y^2+(2-y)^2}{2} dy = c*\int_0^2 \frac{-y^2+4-4y+y^2}{2} dy$$
Simplify and integrate again.
$$c*\int_0^1 -2y+2 dy = c*\left [ -y^2+2y \right ]_0^1 = 1*c $$
Equate to unity for a probability function:
$$1c=1 \rightarrow c=1$$

To find the marginal distributions, we have to do one of the two integrals, accounting for the bounds.
$$f_Y (y) = \int_{x=y}^{x=2-y} x dx = [0.5x^2]_y^{2-y}=\frac{(2-y)^2-y^2}{2} = \frac{4-4y}{2}=2-2y$$
$$f_X (x) = \lbrace \int_0^{y=x} c*xdy \rbrace_{x=0}^{x=1} +\lbrace \int_1^{y=2-x} c*xdy \rbrace_{x=1}^{x=2}$$
$$ f_X (x) = c*x*\left[y\right]_0^x+c*x*\left[y\right]_1^{2-x}$$
$$ = \lbrace x*(x-0)\rbrace+\lbrace x*(2-x-1)\rbrace=\lbrace x^2 \rbrace+\lbrace x-x^2\rbrace$$
The important thing to note about this second distribution is that it is piecewise. That is, if your value of $x$ is less than $1$, use only the first term. Otherwise, evaluate the first term from $0$ to $1$, then evaluate the next
terms from $1$ to $x$.

Comment: So the probability density function has value $-\frac{x}{4}$ inside the region you show? Whatever happened to $f(x,y) \geq 0~ \forall ~x, y$?

Comment: Typo in last line. Fixing it. I was having problems with the formatter, and posted to make sure my LaTeX was right.

Comment: So I first calculated my $c$ wrong, if i get you right. With the correct $c$ my boundary problems for $f_Y(y)$ will be solved?

Comment: Yes. You still have to account for the triangular region, I believe, by integrating the function with respect to the other variable, so that your marginal distributions become functions of one variable.

Comment: did you make a typo when calculating $c$. You write $\left[-y^2+2y\right]_0^1 = 2$ but this has to be $\left[-y^2+2y\right]_0^1 = 1$ i think? I have seen you expanded your answer. I appreciate that :)

Comment: Good catch. Let me fix up my answer.